# jQuery Grid Content Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, infinite-scroll

I need to create a 5 column x 2 row grid to display an "infinite" number of cells (will append with AJAX). I'll have Back & Next buttons on either side of the grid. Because I will be adding content on the fly it seemed like a parent DIV with a fixed size and hidden overflow with a UL with a fixed width and floated LIs was the best option. I would "scroll" by changing the top margin. I want the user to feel like they are scrolling left/right instead of up/down.

I got it working but I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it. Any ideas?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ytJ6Z/

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {height: 100px; width: 100px; overflow: hidden;}
ul {list-style: none; padding: 0; width: 100px;}
li {height: 50px; width: 50px; float: left; }
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
function scroll(toLeft) {

var oldTop = parseInt($("ul").css("margin-top"));
var newTop;
var left;

if (toLeft) {
    newTop = oldTop - 100;
    left = -100;
}
else {
    newTop = oldTop + 100;
    left = 100;
}

$("ul").animate({
    marginLeft: left,
    opacity: 0
}, 500).animate({
    marginTop: newTop,
    marginLeft: -left
}, 0).animate({
    marginLeft: 0,
    opacity: 1
}, 500);
}
```